# Junção 2 query MYSQL em mesma tabela

Tags: mysql

Tenho essa consulta onde resulta a data, a contagem, e a soma de produtos da entrada

```
$result_entrada_mes = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%m/%Y') as data, 
                        COUNT(quantidade) as qnt, 
                        SUM(quantidade) as soma 
                        FROM usuarios GROUP BY MONTH(data), YEAR(data) ORDER BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data)";
```

E possuo essa consulta onde gera os dados de saída de produto, onde o código é quase o mesmo,possuindo apenas uma condição onde não aparece os resultados onde a data da saída estão nulos.

```
$result_saida_mes = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_saida,'%m/%Y') as data1, 
                      COUNT(quantidade) as qnt1, 
                        SUM(quantidade) as soma1 
                       FROM usuarios 
                      WHERE data_saida IS NOT NULL 
                      GROUP BY MONTH(data_saida), YEAR(data_saida) ORDER BY YEAR(data_saida), MONTH(data_saida)";
```

Gostaria de unir essas duas consultas para poder inserir os codigos em um grafico, gerando duas linhas, uma de grafico de entrada, e outra de saida, como posso unir essas duas consultas para exibir em um `while` apenas?

Comment: já pensou em usar `UNION`?  os campos são os mesmos, deve funcionar bem: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html

Comment: Caso deseje os dados das entradas e saídas numa mesma linha você pode utilizar um self FULL OUTER JOIN on (entrada.data = saida.data_saida), onde entrada e sida são diferentes papeis da tabela usuarios.

Answer (score 0):

> **UNION** combina o resultado de execução das duas queries.

```
$result = "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data,'%m/%Y') as data, 
                 COUNT(quantidade) as qnt, 
                 SUM(quantidade) as soma 
            FROM usuarios GROUP BY MONTH(data), YEAR(data) ORDER BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data)
          UNION
          SELECT DATE_FORMAT(data_saida,'%m/%Y') as data, 
                 COUNT(quantidade) as qnt, 
                 SUM(quantidade) as soma 
            FROM usuarios 
           WHERE data_saida IS NOT NULL 
           GROUP BY MONTH(data_saida), YEAR(data_saida) ORDER BY YEAR(data_saida), MONTH(data_saida)";
```